# Why is that when I define a pagestyle with fancyhdr it's shown different for the first page and the others?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, pagestyle

So I am trying to define a style for a work I have to do and I wanted to put two images for header and the page number in the foot of each page. And my code seems to so, but the first page is shown different than the others. In the first one, the header is closer to text than in the other pages and also the page number is shown upper than in the other pages. Why is this if I am using the same pagestyle for all the pages? Thank you in advance. Any answer is very much aprecciated. I'll paste my code right under:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  headheight=1cm,
  includehead,includefoot,
  heightrounded, 
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%definimos un estilo de página para usarlo luego (le ponemos nombre):
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=1.5cm]{seccion-fisica-original.png}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=1.5cm]{logotipo-IEO.Captura-web.png}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

%abrimos el documento y hacemos la portada:
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\centering
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=3cm]{seccion-fisica-original.png}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=2.5cm]{logotipo-IEO.Captura-web.png}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}




{\bfseries\LARGE Universidad de La Laguna\par}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\scshape\Large Facultad de Ciencias: Sección de Física \par}
\vspace{3cm}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4mm}
{\scshape\Huge Memoria pr\'acticas externas \par}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4mm}

\vspace{8cm}
{\Large José María Ramos Fernández \par}
{\Large Junio 2021 \par}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\pagestyle{myfancy}
\section*{ALBERTO}
```

Comment: Unrelated: you probably don't want to use the figure env inside the title page, or the subfigure for that matter. Neither are needed here. Image hfill image does the same.

Comment: Tried out, it worked. Thank you, didn't know, I'm kinda new to writing in Latex.

Comment: Look in the log file, it tells you to change `\headheight`. And also you have an old version of `fancyhdr`. With the newer version (4) there will be no difference, but you get the warning for every page.

Comment: Thank you, now it fits perfect!